# Grouping lines starting at the same position in ModernCV

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I would like to list skills in my CV, but using `\cvitem` looks bad because the second line does not start at the same position as the first...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for accents

\name{John}{Smith}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Key skills}
\cvitem{Languages}{%
    Proficient in: Scala
    \newline
    Comfortable in: C\#
}
\cvitem{Others}{%
    Scrum methodology and teamwork abilities
    \newline
    Object-Oriented API design, UML
}

\end{document}
```

I would like "Comfortable" to start at the same horizontal position as "Proficient".

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired alignment is default in the `classic` and `casual` styles, but not in the `banking` one.  I suggest you define a new command for such items as follows:

```
\newcommand{\cvitemhang}[3][.25em]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
                                                #3\end{tabular}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

This is closely modelled on `\cvitem`.  You can now write

```
\cvitemhang{Languages}{%
    Proficient in: Scala \\
    Comfortable in: C\#
}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{banking}                      
\moderncvcolor{blue}                        
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\newcommand{\cvitemhang}[3][.25em]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
                                                #3\end{tabular}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Key skills}
\cvitemhang{Languages}{%
    Proficient in: Scala \\
    Comfortable in: C\#
}
\cvitemhang{Others}{%
    Scrum methodology and teamwork abilities \\
    Object-Oriented API design, UML
}

\end{document}
```